# Double integral integration!

Tags: integration

Hi there I'm stuck on this bit of integration:
    $(x-1)e^{2x-x^2}$
I have no idea how to do this. I tried distributing the $e^{2x-x^2}$ to x and -1 but it just makes the integral look more messy. I'm thinking it might be integration by parts but that makes it even more messy. Help appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $\frac{d}{dx}(2x-x^2)=-2(x-1)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=2x-x^2$ and you're done.